# How does automatic login work for Netflix games?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, authentication, netflix

I am curious how Netflix manages the authentication flow of their mobile games. For example on Android, I download a game and I am immediately logged in with my Netflix account. How are the game and the Netflix apps communicating under the hood? Does this authentication method has a particular name so I can research it? Thanks :)

Comment: This feature is usually called [Single sign-on (SSO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). I don't know much about it myself but you could look into that

Comment: Can't speak for Android but on iOS, you can do this through Keychain Sharing - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps.

Comment: @Ivo as far as I know, SSO is having one authentication method for multiple platforms. But what I am interested in is why the new installed game from Netflix - which is just downloaded from the app store - already knows my Netflix credentials.
@ Confuselous thanks, will look into it!

Comment: This really is SSO. the name says it also. Signing in a single time. In this case, signing in a single time in your Netflix app so the Netflix authentication counts across multiple apps. Not having the re-enter the credentials it's what's called "true single sign-on" according to the linked wiki page